# How do you add multiple lines to a D3JS line chart where the depedent variable data sources start at different positions along the range?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have MPG data for two different vehicles that looks like this:

```
var data = [{
    "dateAdded": "2017-01-01T16:21:52.921Z",
    "mpg": 25.361,
    "vehicle": "car"
}, {
    "dateAdded": "2017-10-17T11:05:10.280Z",
    "mpg": 17.788,
    "vehicle": "truck"
}, ...]
```

I'm trying to make a D3 JS line chart with a different line for each vehicle on the same graph. Relevant code is below. [See the JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/g27ek8gL/9/).

```
var d3svg = d3.select('svg');
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 60
};
var width = +d3svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = +d3svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// massage the data
data = data.map(function (d) {
    return {
        vehicle: d.vehicle,
        dateAdded: new Date(d.dateAdded),
        mpg: d.mpg
    };
});

console.log(data);

// scales
var xScale = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

// create line for car
var carLine = d3.line()
.x(function(d) { if (d.vehicle.toLowerCase().indexOf('car') > -1) return xScale(d.dateAdded); })
.y(function(d) { if (d.vehicle.toLowerCase().indexOf('car') > -1) return yScale(d.mpg); });

// create line for truck
var truckLine = d3.line()
.x(function(d) { if (d.vehicle.toLowerCase().indexOf('truck') > -1) return xScale(d.dateAdded); })
.y(function(d) { if (d.vehicle.toLowerCase().indexOf('truck') > -1) return yScale(d.mpg); });

// set the domain
xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dateAdded; }));
yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.mpg; })).nice();

// create the outer g tag
var g = d3svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

// add the x-axis
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
.ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m'));

g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis-x')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);

// add the y-axis
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
.tickFormat(d3.format('.1f'));

g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis-y')
    .call(yAxis);

// add the paths that represent the data
g.append('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('class', 'line line-car')
    .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
    .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
    .attr('d', carLine);

g.append('path')
    .datum(data)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('class', 'line line-truck')
    .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
    .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
    .attr('d', truckLine);
```

I can make a graph with the just one of the two vehicle's data, but how do I put both on the same graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating one line generator for each vehicle, which won't work by the way, create just one line generator...

```
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.dateAdded)
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.mpg)
  });
```

... and separate the data for each vehicle:

```
var carData = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.vehicle === "car"
});

var truckData = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.vehicle === "truck"
});
```

Also, don't forget to set the stroke of the paths.

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var data = [{
  "dateAdded": "2017-01-01T16:21:52.921Z",
  "mpg": 25.361,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-02-25T04:43:00.853Z",
  "mpg": 27.45,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-02-28T22:00:22.253Z",
  "mpg": 29.245,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-03-01T01:39:27.160Z",
  "mpg": 23.981,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-03-25T19:50:13.226Z",
  "mpg": 26.293,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-04-06T00:37:33.324Z",
  "mpg": 30.148,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-04-27T02:16:09.503Z",
  "mpg": 23.178,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-04-27T22:15:35.137Z",
  "mpg": 32.362,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-06-05T19:24:16.413Z",
  "mpg": 23.561,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-06-09T14:05:22.063Z",
  "mpg": 33.38,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-06-16T03:12:01.137Z",
  "mpg": 23.41,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-06-24T17:47:26.489Z",
  "mpg": 32.44,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-07-02T10:27:31.963Z",
  "mpg": 25.122,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-07-02T13:24:26.660Z",
  "mpg": 22.021,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-07-09T02:54:02.107Z",
  "mpg": 33.559,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-07-11T15:42:05.969Z",
  "mpg": 30.502,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-07-20T07:08:34.474Z",
  "mpg": 24.176,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-07-29T00:21:18.809Z",
  "mpg": 23.633,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-08-26T11:44:02.211Z",
  "mpg": 31.796,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-08-29T05:16:20.148Z",
  "mpg": 26.962,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-09-01T15:56:22.616Z",
  "mpg": 33.726,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-09-14T06:16:04.025Z",
  "mpg": 25.916,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-09-21T13:09:23.471Z",
  "mpg": 27.461,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-09-28T06:40:38.405Z",
  "mpg": 29.424,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-10-12T15:03:14.717Z",
  "mpg": 32.77,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-10-17T11:05:10.280Z",
  "mpg": 17.788,
  "vehicle": "truck"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-11-01T17:51:15.741Z",
  "mpg": 23.392,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-11-02T18:45:57.081Z",
  "mpg": 20.296,
  "vehicle": "truck"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-11-21T09:07:29.754Z",
  "mpg": 18.263,
  "vehicle": "truck"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-11-25T12:39:35.312Z",
  "mpg": 28.573,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-11-29T21:56:35.318Z",
  "mpg": 19.746,
  "vehicle": "truck"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-12-18T20:28:27.678Z",
  "mpg": 20.992,
  "vehicle": "truck"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2017-12-29T07:56:07.098Z",
  "mpg": 15.433,
  "vehicle": "truck"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2018-01-14T08:30:54.303Z",
  "mpg": 25.375,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2018-01-17T21:27:47.570Z",
  "mpg": 16.602,
  "vehicle": "truck"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2018-01-23T18:55:03.076Z",
  "mpg": 29.325,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2018-01-23T22:15:50.318Z",
  "mpg": 15.516,
  "vehicle": "truck"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2018-02-02T03:04:19.458Z",
  "mpg": 27.97,
  "vehicle": "car"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2018-02-11T08:23:55.474Z",
  "mpg": 17.973,
  "vehicle": "truck"
}, {
  "dateAdded": "2018-02-14T13:46:43.398Z",
  "mpg": 20.791,
  "vehicle": "truck"
}];

var d3svg = d3.select('svg');
var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 60
};
var width = +d3svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = +d3svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// massage the data
data = data.map(function(d) {
  return {
    vehicle: d.vehicle,
    dateAdded: new Date(d.dateAdded),
    mpg: d.mpg
  };
});

// scales
var xScale = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

// create line for car
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.dateAdded)
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.mpg)
  });

// set the domain
xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.dateAdded;
}));
yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.mpg;
})).nice();

var carData = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.vehicle === "car"
});

var truckData = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.vehicle === "truck"
});

// create the outer g tag
var g = d3svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

// add the x-axis
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m'));

g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis axis-x')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .call(xAxis);

// add the y-axis
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
  .tickFormat(d3.format('.1f'));

g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis axis-y')
  .call(yAxis);


// add the paths that represent the data
g.append('path')
  .datum(carData)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('class', 'line line-car')
  .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
  .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr('d', line);

g.append('path')
  .datum(truckData)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('class', 'line line-truck')
  .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
  .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr('d', line);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="900" height="600"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! So the line is simply a plotting tool for a dataset passed to it? I think I get it now :)

Comment: @nhuff717 Yes, exactly. If you want to shorten the code even more, the DRY approach is creating a datta array with inner arrays for each vehicle. Have a look at the code here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955.